# Pattern match not working as expected python

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing, pattern-matching

I was playing around with pattern matches in different html codes of sites I noticed something weird. I used this pattern :

```
pat = <div class="id-app-orig-desc">.*</div>
```

I used it on a app page of the play store(Picked a random app). So according to me it should just give what's between the div tags (ie the description) but that does not happen. I gives everything starting from the first  of the pattern and goes on till the last  of the page completely ignoring  in between. Anyone knows what's happening?!

And I check the length of the list returned it's just 1.

Comment: pat = <div class="id-app-orig-desc">.*</div> this was the pattern used

Comment: you need to escape the double quotes and use `s` modifier to make dot to match a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use a specialized tool - HTML parser. For example, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <div class="id-app-orig-desc">
        Do not try to get me with a regex, please.
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('div', {'class': 'id-app-orig-desc'}).text.strip()
```

Prints:

```
Do not try to get me with a regex, please.
```